# Count only visible records in a report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I have a Dynamics CRM fetch xml report where I have grouped and displayed the case records first by region then by account. Region is another field in another entity but related to the case.
In the report there is an integer parameter and based on the parameter the report should display the records in the report. For example if the parameter value is 3 then report should show only the cases where the account has more than 3 cases.
I am unable to the grouping inside fetch xml and get the details of the case at the same time. So without grouping I get all the records to the report and inside the report I am doing the grouping; and hiding the records using an expression.

Now the problem is when I want to get the totals and counts for each region group and grand totals the hidden records are also get counted. Totals for the Account groups are fine.
Any suggestion to overcome this or any other solution ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with Filter instead of hiding records (provided you're having specific condition).

To get count of rows - Add new column/row outside of group in same tablix. In expression of this newly added textbox enter formula as '=CountRows()'.

Now you can refer this newly added column outside of tablix as ReportItems!texbox_id.Value.